# Datepicker not shown when clicking background image inside text box

Tags: jquery, image

[image]

I used `input type=text` and I set the datepicker using jQuery. I also used an arrow image inside the input field. If I click the input field the datepicker is shown. However if I click the arrow the datepicker is not shown. I set the arrow image using "after" CSS. The following CSS is how I set the arrow image position.

[image]

```css
.date-pic::after {
    content: "";
    width: 28px;
    height: 18px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: no-repeat #ffffff;
    background-image: url(../image/SVG-Icons/down-arrow.svg);
    background-position: center;
    position: absolute;
    right: 14px;
    top: 14px;
}
```